# SQL - Joining a table over itself to find people with same parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, self-join

I have table like this:

```
*Id, Name, Surname, Father Name, Mother Name
---------------------------------------------
*1, John, Green, James, Sue
*2, Michael, Sloan, Barry, Lilly
*3, Sally, Green, Andrew, Molly
*4, Michael, Sloan, Barry, Lilly
*5, Ned, White, James, Sue
```

I want a query that selects rows with the same father name and mother name for given first names. For the example table, when I want to select Johns and Neds with same parents, query should return

```
1, John, Green, James, Sue
5, Ned, White, James, Sue
```

I tried joining table with itself but no matter how I change the where criteria it returned a cartesian product. Any tips?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what you tried till now

Comment: Not clear enough. What do you want as result if in addition you have the following 3 rows: `6  Ned, Blue, Roger, Lucy ---
7, John, Black, Roger, Lucy ---
8, Ned, Orange, Ben, Still`

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-query

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE (FatherName, MotherName) IN 
(SELECT FatherName, MotherName FROM Table WHERE Name='John')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called relational division. However, it's slightly trickier in your case, since it normally returns aggregated data, and you need all rows from the table. So, indeed, a self join is required:

```
select t.*
from dbo.Table t
  inner join (
    select d.FatherName, d.MotherName
    from dbo.Table d
    group by d.FatherName, d.MotherName
    having count(*) > 1
  ) sq on sq.FatherName = t.FatherName
    and sq.MotherName = t.MotherName;
```

In the subquery, you select only `Father+Mother` combinations that have more than 1 entry in the table, and then join it with the table again to output everything from these parents' pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Self-join is appropriate method at this case.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM MyTable AS t1 
INNER JOIN MyTable AS t2
    ON t1.FatherName=t2.FatherName
    AND t1.MotherName=t2.MotherName
    AND t1.Id<>t2.Id 
WHERE t1.Name in ('John', 'Ned')
```

Comment: If the same parents have 3 children, all 3 rows will be duplicated in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (without `group by` and `count(*)`)

```
with fm as
(select fathername, mothername,row_number() over (partition by fathername,    
mothername order by id) rownum
from #tmp1
)
select b.* 
from #tmp1 b
join fm
on b.fathername = fm.fathername
and b.mothername = fm.mothername
where fm.rownum = 2
```